# xml linq retrieving elements in same node

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I was wondering if there is a way to find a list of elements in an XML document using LiNQ where there exist an pair element `<new>` and `<old>`. However, both these elements does not have to be there ie. a XDoc with no `<old>`and but a `<new>` elements. Also I could have a huge XML file with no `<new>` and `<old>` tag.

Here are some few examples (from the same XDoc)

```
<Profile>Your name is <old>Jason</old><new>Sam</new>. It is a pleasure to meet you</Profile>
```

or another element within the same doc

```
<Age>Your age is <new>25</new></Age>
```

Or could be the case

```
<Marriage><old>Married</old></Marriage>
```

So in the end i need a List of the tuple pair {old, new}, in this example it'll be:

{Jason, Sam}

{'', 25}

{Married,''}

My first first attempt was to use this:

```
var oldElement = xml.Descendants().AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Name == "old");
var newElement = xml.Descendants().AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Name == "new");
```

and join the two by looping through the old elements. Obviously this will not work because there could be a case where the old and new count will not match (ie. when there are a whole bunch of new nodes and no old nodes)

Is there a way to get a list of matching pair of new and old under the same parent. In our example the Profile Node has both matching parent, whereas the other two (Age) had only new node and (Marriage) only had old node. So the end result will look like the list above (if no new tags then empty string).

Comment: You have to first define what is the common parent.  if the xml document has ten layers of nested tags is the common parent the 5th tag or the 8th tag?  <root><a><b><c><d><new>123</new><old>456</old></d></c></b></a></root>.  In this case root, a, b, c, d are all parents of old & new.  Without knowing the parent structure you can't randomly locate the parent of old & new.

Comment: Something like: <root>   <profile>Your name is   <new><age></age><marriage></marriage></new>    <old><age></age><marriage></marriage></old>     </profile>   </root>

Comment: @jdweng in your example it should return a list with one element { 456, 123} since they both fall under the node d... If they were in different node ie.  <root><a><new>123</new></a><b><new>55</new><old>3</old></b><c><old>h</old><new>j</new></c></root>

Comment: Will return a list of { ('', 123),(3,55),(h,j)} notice the order too.

Comment: I know what it should return.  But if old is a child of 'b' and new is a child of 'd' what should be returned?  Without defining what parent should be used you can get different results.  Using descendants will cause issues in this case.  You have to determine the common parent of old and new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE :**

In response to your comment, the query would be more complex in such scenario. You can use two sub-queries in this case, say `q1` and `q2`, which you can combine using LINQ `Union()` :

```
var raw = @"<Profile>
  <new>Your</new> name is 
  <old>Jason</old>
  <new>Sam</new>. It is a pleasure 
  <old>have</old>to meet you
  <old>Jason</old>
  <new>Mr. Sam</new>
</Profile>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(raw);

//create Tuple from all <old> elements no matter it has matching <new> element or not
var q1 = from old in doc.Descendants("old")
         let nextSibling = old.NextNode
         let _new = nextSibling != null && nextSibling is XElement && ((XElement)nextSibling).Name == "new" ? ((XElement)nextSibling).Value : ""
         select Tuple.Create((string)old, _new);

//create Tuple from all <new> elements that don't have matching <old> element
var q2 = from _new in doc.Descendants("new")
         let prevSibling = _new.PreviousNode
         where prevSibling == null || !(prevSibling is XElement) || ((XElement)prevSibling).Name != "old"
         select Tuple.Create("", (string)_new);

var result = q1.Union(q2);
```

Notice, however, that the output would be in *'query order'* instead of *'document order'* i.e result of `q1` will come first, followed by result of `q2` :

```
(Jason, Sam)
(have, )
(Jason, Mr. Sam)
(, Your)
```

If the order is important, then more conditional logic will be involved. So, IMHO, plain `foreach` loop would be more manageable then LINQ in this situation :

```
var result = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
foreach (var e in doc.Descendants().Where(o => o.Name == "old" || o.Name == "new"))
{
    XElement _old, _new;
    //if current element is an <old> ...
    if (e.Name == "old")
    {
        _old = e;
        //if the next sibling is a <new>
        if (e.NextNode != null && e.NextNode is XElement && ((XElement)e.NextNode).Name == "new")
        {
            _new = ((XElement)e.NextNode);
        }
        //else: <old> without matching <new>
        else _new = null;
        result.Add(Tuple.Create((string)_old, (string)_new));
    }
    //else: current element is a <new> ...
    else
    {
        //make sure we add current <new> to the result only if it doesn't have matching <old>
        //otherwise it would have been covered by the `if (e.Name == "old")` block
        if (e.PreviousNode == null || !(e.PreviousNode is XElement) || ((XElement)e.PreviousNode).Name != "old")
        {
            _new = e;
            _old = null;
            result.Add(Tuple.Create((string)_old, (string)_new));
        }
    }
}
```

---

**INITIAL ANSWER :**

Assuming that `<old>` and `<new>` elements are linked by sharing the same parent element, and there is maximum of one pair in a parent element, you can try this way :

```
var raw = @"<root>
<Profile>Your name is <old>Jason</old><new>Sam</new>. It is a pleasure to meet you</Profile>
<Age>Your age is <new>25</new></Age>
<Marriage><old>Married</old></Marriage>
</root>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(raw);

var result = doc.Descendants()
                //filter element that has child <old> or <new> or both :
                .Where(o => o.Element("old") != null || o.Element("new") != null)
                //return tuple of old value - new value from current parent element :
                .Select(o => Tuple.Create((string)o.Element("old"), (string)o.Element("new")));

foreach (var r in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r);
}
```

**output :**

```
(Jason, Sam)
(, 25)
(Married, )
```

Comment: Great that works! but i have a small issue. i forgot to say that in the same node it could have more than 1 `old` and/or `new` tag they are followed by their pair in the order `old` first then `new`. IE. `<Profile>Your name is <old>Jason</old><new>Sam</new>. It is a pleasure <old>have</old>to meet you<old>Jason<old><new>Mr. Sam</new></Profile>`
in the previous case it should be 
{Jason, Sam}
{have, }
{Jason, Mr. Sam}
and the rest of the doc @har07

Comment: Check the **UPDATE** section.